# JMX Notifications from MBean not listened/subscribed.What happens to the Notifications?

Tags: notifications, logstash, jmx, spring-jmx, notification-listener

I am using `JMX MBeans` in `spring 4` framework. I handle notifications from JMX mBean and process them as events.

For testing alternate approach, I just commented out notification handling part. This implies that my JMX Mbean continues to publish notifications and I am just ignoring them.

P.S:
I handle the JMX notifications via `logstash`. For testing I have commented out `Logstash` configuration

What happens to the Notification? Where it will be stored?
Will it impact memory /pile up in application?

Answer (score 2):

JMX notifications are an implementation of the observer pattern. With this pattern, events are not stored, so there is no memory issue.

`NotificationBroadcaster` JavaDoc:

> When an MBean emits a notification, it considers each listener that has been added with addNotificationListener and not subsequently removed with removeNotificationListener. If a filter was provided with that listener, and if the filter's isNotificationEnabled method returns false, the listener is ignored. Otherwise, the listener's handleNotification method is called with the notification...

### See also

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationBroadcaster.html
- [Java Management Extensions (JMX) - Best Practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/best-practices-jsp-136021.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen#mozTocId420028)

### Lapsed Listener Problem

The observer pattern link refers to this problem. To be clear, this potential memory link is different than what you worried about originally (storing notifications). This memory leak is caused by listeners not being deregistered, for example the logstash listener. If a listener is not deregistered, then it may not be garbage collected.

If you are concerned about this, you need to confirm that commenting out the logstash configuration prevents the listener from ever registering in the first place (it probably does). Regardless, this is probably not an issue for you, because it is just one listener object. Your concern about notifications was more serious because notifications are continuously created.

Comment: Thank you. But with First link on Observer Pattern suggests LapsedListenerProblem which could cause memory leak. I am just confused.

Comment: I updated my answer to address this concern, @ArivazhaganJeganathan.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging of code flow of `sendNotification` Method in Java:
My findings below:

```
Flow of sendNotification Method: 
org.springframework.jmx.export.notification.ModelMBeanNotificationPublisher
javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean (Sendnotification)
javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport
```

Method in `NotificationBroadcasterSupport` sends notifications to listeners which are registered only (based on `listenersList` within the class file). If no listeners are registered, then it skips sending notifications.

Hence from this I assume/conclude that Notifications are not stored anywhere.

As @DavidS suggested, if we fail to removeNotificationListener after registering and do not want to receive notifications, we would end up listeners processing notifications. Possible cause of memory leak.